# Cannot key in anything in Textfields after adding KeyListener

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a Sudoku, but after adding KeyListener to the Textfield, I cannot key in anything in to the text field. What's wrong with my code?

I have already tried the code below:

```
//add listener in the previous code

for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE && !found; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE && !found; ++col) {
         tfCells[row][col].addKeyListener(new KeyAction());
     }
}

//implements the listener
private class KeyAction implements KeyListener {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt){}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    // Get the source object that fired the event
       JTextField source = (JTextField)e.getSource();

       // Scan JTextFileds for all rows and columns, and match with the source object
      boolean found = false;
      for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE && !found; ++row) {
              for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE && !found; ++col) {
             if (tfCells[row][col] == source) {
                 rowSelected = row;
                 colSelected = col;
                  found = true;  // break the inner/outer loops
              }
            }
      }
          /* 1. Get the input String 
             2. Assume that the solution is unique. Compare the input number 
                with the number in the puzzle[rowSelected][colSelected].  
                If they are the same,set the background to green(Color.GREEN); 
                otherwise, set to red (Color.RED).
       */

           String inputString = tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].getText();
       if(Integer.parseInt(inputString)==puzzle[rowSelected][colSelected]) {

           tfCells[rowSelected[colSelected].setBackground(OPEN_CELL_TEXT_YES);
           masksGen.setCellMasks(rowSelected, colSelected, false);
       tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setEditable(false);
       }else {
    tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(OPEN_CELL_TEXT_NO);
    }


    //Check conflicts in row and col, the bg turn blue
    for(int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; ++row){
        if((tfCells[row][colSelected] == tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected]) && (row != rowSelected)){
        tfCells[row][colSelected].setBackground(CONFLICT_BGCOLOR);
        }
    }

    for(int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; ++col){
        if((tfCells[rowSelected][col] == tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected]) && (col != colSelected)){
        tfCells[rowSelected][col].setBackground(CONFLICT_BGCOLOR);
        }
    }

     }
}
```

I want the listener to check and response when I key in a number. Could you help me find out why I cannot key in anything?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the culprit:

```
tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setEditable(false);
```

It prevents the character to be entered into the JTextField, because the character would be added AFTER the key listener's execution. Therefore your typed char does never arrive in the text field.

I took the liberty of reformatting your code a bit, before making a few suggestions.

```
//add listener in the previous code
KeyAction action = new KeyAction();
for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; ++col) {
        tfCells[row][col].addKeyListener(action);
    }
}

//implements the listener
protected class KeyAction extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        // Get the source object that fired the event
        JTextField source = (JTextField)e.getSource();

        // Scan JTextFileds for all rows and columns, and match with the source object
        FIND_FIELD:
        for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; ++col) {
                if (tfCells[row][col] == source) {
                    rowSelected = row;
                    colSelected = col;
                    break FIND_FIELD;
                }
            }
        }
        /* 1. Get the input String 
           2. Assume that the solution is unique. Compare the input number 
              with the number in the puzzle[rowSelected][colSelected].  
              If they are the same,set the background to green(Color.GREEN); 
              otherwise, set to red (Color.RED).
         */

        String inputString = tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].getText();
        if (Integer.parseInt(inputString)==puzzle[rowSelected][colSelected]) {

            tfCells[rowSelected[colSelected].setBackground(OPEN_CELL_TEXT_YES);
            masksGen.setCellMasks(rowSelected, colSelected, false);
            tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setEditable(false);
        } else {
            tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected].setBackground(OPEN_CELL_TEXT_NO);
        }


        //Check conflicts in row and col, the bg turn blue
        for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; ++row) {
            if ((tfCells[row][colSelected] == tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected])
                    && (row != rowSelected)){
                tfCells[row][colSelected].setBackground(CONFLICT_BGCOLOR);
            }
        }

        for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; ++col) {
            if ((tfCells[rowSelected][col] == tfCells[rowSelected][colSelected])
                    && (col != colSelected)) {
                tfCells[rowSelected][col].setBackground(CONFLICT_BGCOLOR);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i only set it uneditble key in tbe correct answer. in the previous code i did assigned the textfeild to be editable.